# Как в методе findSmallest убрать элемент массива из последующего поиска?

Tags: java, сортировка, сортировка-выбором

Как в методе findSmallest убрать элемент массива из последующего поиска?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] test = {1,4,52,26,43,20,4,23};
        int[] answer = selectionSort(test);
        returnAnswer(answer);
    }

    public static int findSmallest(int[] nums) {
        int smallest = nums[0];
        int smallest_index = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i< nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = nums[i];
                smallest_index = i;
            }
        }
        return smallest_index;
    }

    public static int[] selectionSort(int[] nums) {
        int[] newNums = new int [nums.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int smallest = findSmallest(nums);
            newNums[i] = nums[smallest];
        }
        return newNums;
    }

    public static void returnAnswer(int[] answer) {
        for (int n : answer) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: При использовании обычных массивов такого понятия как "убрать" нет вовсе, если только вручную не создавать каждый раз новый массив без очередного ненужного элемента. Чтобы можно было динамически удалять элементы, вместо массивов можно использовать коллекции. Например, `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортировка выбором предусматривает [перестановку найденного минимума](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC) в начало неотсортированной части массива, а в представленном коде создаётся пустая копия массива, которая должна заполняться поочерёдно найденными минимумами, то есть исходный массив остаётся неотсортированным.

Для решения задачи собственно сортировки *можно* переписать метод `findSmallest`, чтобы он принимал начальный индекс, с которого следует начинать поиск.

```java
public static int findSmallest(int[] nums, int from) {
    int smallest = nums[from];
    int smallest_index = from;
    boolean swap = false;
    for (int i = from + 1; i< nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = nums[i];
            smallest_index = i;
            swap = true;
        }
    }
    if (swap) {
        int t = nums[from];
        nums[from] = smallest;
        nums[smallest_index] = t;
    }
    return from;
}

public static int[] selectionSort(int[] nums) {
    int[] newNums = new int [nums.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        newNums[i] = nums[findSmallest(nums, i)];
    }
    return newNums;
}
```

При такой реализации оба массива будут отсортированы, и в принципе нет нужды создавать дополнительный массив

---

Если же нужна реализация с запоминанием индексов найденных минимумов и последующим игнорированием, то для этого лучше всего подойдёт сет, который соответственно следует передавать в метод `findSmallest`.
Очевидно, при такой реализации получается неоптимальный расход памяти -- кроме дополнительного массива для хранения результата добавляется сет.

Выйдет что-то вроде:

```java
public static int[] selectionSort(int[] nums) {
    int[] newNums = new int [nums.length];
    Set<Integer> indexes = new LinkedHashSet<>(nums.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int min = findSmallest(nums, indexes);
        indexes.add(min);
        newNums[i] = nums[min];
    }
    return newNums;
}
 
public static int findSmallest(int[] nums, Set<Integer> indexes) {
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int smallest_index = -1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i< nums.length; i++) {
        if (indexes.contains(i)) {
            continue;  // пропускаем индекс известного минимума
        }
        if (smallest_index == -1 || nums[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = nums[i];
            smallest_index = i;
        }
    }
    return smallest_index;
}
```

При такой реализации сортировки создаётся новый отсортированный массив, а исходный остаётся неотсортированным.